How can I withdraw ERC20 tokens from this proxy contract?
I have an contract exactly like this: https://etherscan.io/address/0xd9db270c1b5e3bd161e8c8503c55ceabee709552#code
How can I withdraw ERC20 tokens from it?
Please write an nodejs example or the value what needs to input in any field of the execTransaction action.
